# Probability of a document is not the same as 1/number of documents, is it?

Tags: information-retrieval

Currently, I am writing code in Python for a paper that I'm reading and has been implemented in R already by the author.

For this paper we have a corpus with $n$ documents and $m$ words.

In one of the steps, I have to calculate the probability of document $j$ as follows:

> *Step 4* We use document-term matrices with the GTW methods in step 2 (Words ⨉ Documents matrix) to find $\mathbf{P(D_j)}$ or probability of document $j$: $$ P(D_j) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m (W_i,D_j)}{\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n (W_i,D_j)} $$

Here:

- $W_i$ = word $i$
- $D_j$ = document $j$

I interpret this as computing  a vector of length $n$ in which each cell is the sum of GTW values of all words $W_i$ within one document $D_j$, divided by the total sum in all the documents.

However, in the R code, $P(D_j)$ is calculated as a vector of length $n$ where each cell has the value 1/number of documents. Based on my interpretation, this implementation does not align with the formula.

Am I interpreting the formula correctly?

Comment: Do you have definition of $(W,D)$?

Comment: No, they don't provide that. However, in step 2, I have created several a `n x m` matrix (called GTW), which assigns weights to all non-zero cells. Here they mention that they use the GTW matrix from step two to calculate the probability of document j. Therefore, the most likely interpretation of (W_i,D_j) seems to be the cell in GTW associated with word i and document j.

Comment: If assume, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix example in General Concept,  that $(W,D)$ is simply amount of words $W$ in document $D$, then formula $(9)$ have in numerator count of all words for document $D_j$, while denominator is amount of all words in all documents. Such approach, of course, gives probability, but does it suite you?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is indeed. And then through GTW some weighting is assigned to each non-zero value from the document term matrix. However, my question is in regards to the author's implementation. He has implemented formula 9 as a n-dimensional vector in which each cell has the (same) value: 1/n. This implementation seems to be different than what formula 9 states, do you agree?

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to agree without full context. May be, in paper there is some additional consideration.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper?

Comment: I have contacted the author and he mentioned that both methods are acceptable. However, they are indeed different. Here is the paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40815-017-0327-9